# Excel VBA Method 'Range' of object'_global' failed error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I can't for the life of my figure out why I'm getting "'Range' of object'_global' failed" on my do while statement. It's like the range named RC3 isn't being recognized. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

Dim Allrws As Range
Dim Rws As Range
Dim RC2 As Range
Dim RC3 As Range
Dim I As Integer
Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

With Application

'.ScreenUpdating = False ' don't spam the interface with selections

    With ActiveSheet

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Put the number of the last row in LastRow

    End With

    Set Allrws = Range("A2:S" & CStr(LastRow))  ' set range to be observed

    For Each Rws In Allrws.Rows   ' for each row in the range of Allrws call it Rws and do the following with it

        Set RC2 = Rws.Offset(0, 3).Resize(1, 1)      ' move and resize the range of RC2 to include only the cell under column D
        Set RC3 = Rws.Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 1)      ' move and resize the range of RC3 to include only the cell under column I        
        I = 0   ' initilize the rows deleted counter

            Do While (Range(RC3).Value <> "" And I < 30)    ' as long as RC points to a empty cell and we haven't removed more then 30 rows keep removing rows                                                             

                If (range(RC2).Value = "Permit & Design" Or range(RC2).Value = "Miscellanious") Then 'don't delete row if Permit & Design or Miscellanious is in the cell under column D

                  I = 30        ' escape the loop if true

                Else

                  Selection.EntireRow.Delete      ' delete the selected row if false

                  I = I + 1                       ' add 1 to the counter

                End If        

            Loop                                   ' Go back to the start of the Do While

    Next Rws                    ' go back to the For Each and put the next row in Rws

    .ScreenUpdating = True      ' now update the interface with the changes

end with

end sub
```

Comment: `RC3` is already a Range, so no need for range(range), just `RC3.Value`

Comment: `Selection.EntireRow.Delete` seems to be deleting an unspecified, arbitrary user-selected row. Probably not what you intend. Why work off `Selection` anyway?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks! I forgot to change that back to RC2.EntireRow.Delete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Do While (Range(RC3).Value <> "" And I < 30)
```

[`RC3` is a `Range` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901895/excel-vba-method-range-of-object-global-failed-error-1004#comment74837789_43901895). What `Range(SomeRangeObject)` does is really `Range(SomeRangeObject.Value)`, so unless `RC3.Value` contains a valid range address string, that *unqualified* `Range` call is going to blow up.

Note *unqualified*: your code *implicitly* works off the `ActiveSheet`:

```
Set Allrws = Range("A2:S" & CStr(LastRow))
```

Whenever `Range` is used like this, it's implicitly doing `ActiveSheet.Range`, through the `_Global` hidden module.

Unqualified `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` and `Names` calls are all implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`, and the misunderstanding of this fact is the reason behind every single "Related" question in the side bar (the ones I checked anyway), and there are thousands more of the same on this site: it's an *extremely* common source of bugs. So, **qualify worksheet member calls** and avoid problems.

Your code *happens* to work (well, given the above modification). If the `With ActiveSheet` block was changed to `With Sheet12`, you would start seeing issues stemming from all the unqualified `Range` calls.